# IO#select returns IO objects despite EOF -- is this expected?

Tags: ruby

I'm confused about how IO#select works in Ruby.  I'm told [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_m_kernel.html#Kernel.select) that it should only return the given IO objects if they are ready to be read.  However, I'm getting IO objects returned even when `eof?` is true.

Am I missing something?

Here's some code that exhibits my confusion:

```rb
require 'open3'
stdin, stdout, stderr, thread = Open3.popen3('true')
eval_print = lambda {|code| puts "#{code} -> #{eval(code).inspect}" }
eval_print.call('stdout')
eval_print.call('stderr')
eval_print.call('select([stdout, stderr], nil, nil, 1)')
eval_print.call('stdout.eof?')
eval_print.call('stderr.eof?')
eval_print.call('stdout.gets')
eval_print.call('stderr.gets')
eval_print.call('select([stdout, stderr], nil, nil, 1)')
```

The output of this code (on Ruby version 1.9.2p136) is:

```
stdout -> #<IO:fd 5>
stderr -> #<IO:fd 7>
select([stdout, stderr], nil, nil, 1) -> [[#<IO:fd 5>, #<IO:fd 7>], [], []]
stdout.eof? -> true
stderr.eof? -> true
stdout.gets -> nil
stderr.gets -> nil
select([stdout, stderr], nil, nil, 1) -> [[#<IO:fd 5>, #<IO:fd 7>], [], []]
```

Shouldn't `select` return `nil` in both of those cases?

Comment: Are you aware that the documentation you're pointing to is from the first edition of "Programming Ruby" which is for Ruby 1.6? The current edition is the third one, which is for Ruby 1.9. Instead, you may want to google for Ruby RDoc.

Comment: Yup, I'm aware.  Sadly, the current docs (v1.9.2) seem to be lacking anything of value for [IO.select](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/IO.select) or [Kernel.select](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/Kernel:select).  If you know of good current docs for `select`, please share.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't blame you for being a little confused, the official docs are, shall we say, a little thin on what `select` is supposed to do.

`IO.select` is probably just a thin wrapper around the `select` system call so we'll have a look at that (which is quite well documented). From the [Linux man pages](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/select.2.html):

> Those listed in *readfds* will be watched to see if characters become available
>   for reading (more precisely, to see if a read will not block; in particular, **a
>   file descriptor is also ready on end-of-file**)

Emphasis mine. So, `select` is more about "will it block" than it is about "are there bytes waiting for me" and an EOF is a non-blocking state so `select` considers a file descriptor that is in an end-of-file condition to be ready for reading.

Comment: So `select` isn't broken, though the documentation is? :)

Comment: @Andrew: Do you mean the [`IO.select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M000885) docs or the [`Kernel.select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001406) docs? Ahem. And what are doing shaving off your beard?

Comment: I equated "thin on the ground" as "broken", even if it isn't incorrect. I just couldn't resist the "select is broken" meme. Anyway, I actually shaved my beard last June (I was told by a date I'd be more attractive without it), but I only updated my gravatar so that RubyKaigi attendees wouldn't be looking for someone with a beard this July!

Comment: Ah, very good.  Thanks, that's helpful.  So I'll need to monitor EOF independently of the `select` call.